# How can I move/remove my post?

Tags: support, migration

I have a question about my Super User post: [How to use MCMC.qpcr package in R without PCR efficiency data?](https://superuser.com/questions/1157170/how-to-use-mcmc-qpcr-package-in-r-without-pcr-efficiency-data)

Somebody commented that I posted question in wrong site. How can I remove/move my question?

Comment: Flag it for a moderator to look at and explain why you thing it needs moving.

Answer (score 5):

#### How can I remove/move my question?

1. Flag your question "in need of moderator intervention" and ask a mod to move it (be specific about where you want it moved to), **or**
2. Delete your question (using the "delete" link underneath your question) and post a new question using the "Ask Question" button on http://stackoverflow.com.